# Show keyboard web application

Tags: javascript, android, web

I've a web application, then I need to work on mobile devices, mainly in Android.
The issue is that after some processing, the focus change to a text input then I need that when it happens automatically the virtual keyboard appear without the user need to tap over the input.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The focus() and click() prevents that virtual keyboard appear to avoid annoying behavior. The only way to do that is to call the focus() or click() inside a user-evento context for example inside a click method callback.